# In sklearn.KNeighborsClassifier, I got error: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

I have a problem with the program I created to classify images. I store my image in an array

```
arr = np.concatenate((X1, Y1))
```

where has size : (80, 128, 128, 3)
and i have another one :

```
arr2 = np.concatenate((X2, Y2))
```

where has size : (20, 128, 128, 3)
I will make array into training data. and create target :

```
a= np.full((1, 40), 1)
b= np.full((1, 40), 2)
arr3 = np.concatenate((a, b))
```

and set into knn algorithm

```
knn=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3) #define K=3
knn.fit(arr,arr3)
res = knn.predict(arr2)
print(res)
```

I don't get results and there is an error: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2.

I've also tried to reshape arr and arr2 :

```
arr5 = arr.reshape(-1,1)
arr6 = arr2.reshape(-1,1)
```

but also getting errors: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

I need your opinion about this to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can read [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn-neighbors-kneighborsclassifier), For using `sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier` and `.fit(X,y)` should have shape like :

> fit(X, y): Fit the k-nearest neighbors classifier from the training dataset.
>
> > Parameters :
> > X{array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features) or (n_samples, n_samples) if metric=’precomputed’
> > Training data.
> > y{array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_outputs)
> > Target values.

For this reason, you need to reshape `arr or x_train like (80, 128*128*3)` and `arr2 or x_test like (20, 128*128*3)` and `y or arr3 like (80)`:

*(for this reshaping we can use `numpy.reshape(-1) like below.)*

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import numpy as np

arr  = np.random.rand(80,128,128,3)
arr2 = np.random.rand(20,128,128,3)

a= np.full((1, 40), 1)
b= np.full((1, 40), 2)
arr3 = np.concatenate((a, b))

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
knn.fit(arr.reshape(80,-1), arr3.reshape(-1))

res = knn.predict(arr2.reshape(20,-1))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1]
```

Comment: thank you, and how can i know which image it is, is there a way to print the name of the image?

Comment: @ryand, do you mean label of each images?

Comment: in a different case if i have 100 images it consists of 2 classes there are 50 images each. and then I put in x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2, stratify=y, random_state=42) and start to fit the training data and then make predictions and get the results as above, how do I know which image data is x_test?..is there a way to get the image name? @I'mahdi

Comment: x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test shape:  (80, 49152), (20, 49152), (80,),(20,)

Comment: @ryand, I answer your question.

Comment: can we discuss more in chat, i need your help please@I'mahdi

Comment: @ryand, tomorrow is better, do you OK?

Comment: I can't ask here because of the limit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245522/discussion-between-imahdi-and-ryand).

Comment: @ryand, I'm here two hours later

Comment: @ryand, i'm on discussion

Comment: ok @I'mahdi.....

Comment: im on @I'mahdi......